# In Python, is None a unique object?

Tags: python, object, nonetype

In my test code, why the `print` results for tuple and None are different? It seems that a, b point to the same object `None`, but c, d point to different objects, though their values are the same (both equal to `(a,b)`).

I know that `is` keyword checks for the object lying behind rather than just compares value like `==`. And here I use tuple because I think tuple is immutable so that at least it's not a matter of whether the object is mutable or immutable.

But why variables a, b don't create and point to two different `None` objects as c, d do to tuple?

```
a=None
b=None
c=(1,2)
d=(1,2)
print(a is b)
print(c is d)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`None`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/none.html) is a singleton object: only one instance of it can ever exist. So objects referencing `None` will always have the same identity, and two or more of such objects will always pass the identity  (object equality) test:

```
>>> a = None
>>> b = None
>>> c = None
>>> a is b is c
True
```

Same applies to `True` and `False`

```
>>> d = True
>>> (a is b is c) is d # proof of concept only
True
```

Comment: Just for sure, for singleton object you said like None, True and False, basically `is` and `==` work exactly the same? Thanks BTW.

Comment: For booleans, it is sufficient to use the `==` for testing (or the object itself) as objects have truthy and falsy values. `c = 1` will pass `c == True` (better to use c directly as in `if c: ...`) but not `c is True`. Be careful to only use `is` if and only if you intend to check identity not equality

Comment: Wait, since when was `a is b is c` not parsed as `(a is b) is c`? I thought that only applied to the normal comparison operators. **edit:** `'a' in 'ab' in 'abc'` is valid too

Comment: @Eric [comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) can be chained arbitrarily. Adding a grouping parenthesis forces the interpreter to evaluate the items in the `()` first then the others. One'll have to be more careful when adding parenthesis to chained comparisons.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: `in` is not in that list, yet still chains

Comment: @Eric It does not have to be. The behavior of `in` in this case is well defined. More like: `'ab'.__contains__('a') and 'abc'.__contains__('ab')`. As evaluated from left to right.

Answer (score 7):

[`None` object is a singleton in python.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#None) Hence the result.

Whereas for `c` and `d`, it creates separate tuples.

From your example:

```
>>> id(None)
4454442584
>>> id(a)
4454442584
>>> id(b)
4454442584
>>> id(c)
4463917464
>>> id(d)
4463865584
```

Answer (score 3):

The 'is' operator compares the objects behind the variables as you figured out.

```
a=None
b=None
print(a is b)
>True #both None are the same instanciations or objects
```

The None Object in Python is a singleton (https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/none.html) and therefore a singleton restricts the instantiation of a class to one object (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).